# Reading formatted text from a file

Tags: matlab, textscan

I'm tring to read the follwing text file with Matlab:

```
00000008.jpg 1 2 1
00000001.jpg 1 2 1
00000054.jpg 1 2 1
```

What I want to extract is each column of each line in order to access it.

I've tried the following code:

```
fileLabels = fopen('file.txt');
C = textscan(fileLabels,'%s %n %n %n');
celldisp(C)
```

And it returns:

```
C{1}{1} =
00000008.jpg

C{1}{2} = 
00000001.jpg

C{1}{3} =
00000054.jpg
```

Which is good, because this way I have the first string separated in cells, but, when I try to get the numbers, they appear this way:

```
C{2} =
     1
     1
     1

C{3} =
     2
     2
     2

C{4} =
     1
     1
     1
```

Instead of having them separated in cells, they appear all in one cell. If I try to access to one cell of the 2º column, it appears the following error:

```
>> C{2}{1}
Cell contents reference from a non-cell array object.
```

Please, anyone knows how to extract each column separately line by line?

Comment: Try `C{2}(1)`, does it work?

Comment: Yeah, I think what Ander said will work. It's a vector within a cell.

Comment: Yes it works! Thanks @AnderBiguri !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numbers are in an array rather than cell, which should be more convenient for later process. You can access the numbers by

```
C{2}(1) % C{2} is 3x1 array, not cell
```

If this does not fit your need, you may try some function like importdata.